# Should I build my non-mobile web site in Bootstrap?

Tags: web-development, website-design, responsive-webdesign, bootstrap

w3schools.com defines Bootstrap as "... framework for developing responsive, mobile-first web sites".

If I am not interested that much in building a mobile-compatible web site (I am but it is not my first target), can I still use bootstrap? There is a batter framework in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, you can still use boostrap framework to make webpages for desktop or laptop as well.** They use media query to make webpages responsive, but it does not mean, only boostrap can make mobile responsive webpages, if you know media queries then you can also make any webpage responsive.

Boostrap is big framework, lot's of CSS style will not used in webpage, but still browser need to download/load those css styles, which make webpage big.

Feel free to go with boostrap, you can make website for desktop/computer + mobile responsive. - [For more reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227000/pros-cons-of-switching-to-twitter-bootstrap).